# Skip specific package version using dnf

Tags: fedora, dnf

I know how to install a specific version or how to exclude a package from transactions, but I want to mark a specific version of package to be skipped. Is that possible?

Background: `gdk-pixbuf2-2.42.9` has a known issue, which is already [fixed in upstream](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gdk-pixbuf/-/issues/216). It's just a matter of time, when that update will become available in fedora 36. Anyway, I downgraded that package and still want to `dnf update` my machine, without remembering: hey, exclude that package - or worse: exclude it using `dnf.conf` and forget about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install `dnf-plugins-core`
2. `sudo dnf versionlock add PACKAGE` to lock it.

If you need to unlock it, you'll have to pass `sudo dnf versionlock delete PACKAGE`.

You can read more about it [here](https://dnf-plugins-core.readthedocs.io/en/latest/versionlock.html).

Comment: Thank you very much! Although I had to install the plugin by using `dnf install 'dnf-command(versionlock)'` (suggested by `dnf versionlock` command).